# Javascript animate multiple nodes with forEach

Tags: javascript, animation, dom-events, mouseover

I'm trying to animate multiple help icons via `document.getElementsByClassName()`. I know it returns an array like object which is actually a node list of all elements which have the same class, I also know that I can access individual items by appending an `index[4]` of the node I want to access. However I'm unsure how to access all nodes. I tried `[*].animate()` but that did not work. I also tried the `forEach =>` function listed below but its still not working, I tried `[0-8]` nothing happened.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

I know I could wrap it in a for, while or forEach loop or even a switch statement but this is the code I have so far:

```
const infIco = document.getElementsByClassName('helpIco')[*].forEach(item =>{
    item.addEventListener('mouseover',(e) => {
        this.animate([
            { transform: 'scale(1)', opacity:1},
            { transform: 'scale(1.42) rotate(22deg)', opacity: .8},
            { transform: 'scale(1)', opacity: 1},
                ], {
                duration: 1560,           // ms
                easing: 'ease-in-out',    // 'linear', bezier curve, etc..cubic-bezier(.43,.95,.85,.14)
                delay: 4,                 // ms
                iteration: Infinity,      // Or number
                direction: 'normal',      // 'normal', 'reverse' etc...
                fill: 'forwards'          // 'backwards', 'both', 'none', 'auto.'
        })
      // Todo...
    })
});
```

I know the `.animate()` part is working as I also have this attached to another item and its working fine. Maybe a little glitchy sometimes but that's most likely due to having an old graphics card and a crud computer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Array.from( list )` method or the `...` spread operator,

to make an actual array from node list:

```
Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName('helpIco') ).forEach( function(){ /*...*/ });

[ ...document.getElementsByClassName('helpIco') ].forEach( function(){ /*...*/ });
```

But `getElementsBy...` returns a «live» list, which will update each time, if any of it's element used... In most cases it's better to use `querySelectorAll('.class-with-dot')` instead. It collects a node list only once, and has a built-in forEach method.

Comment: Array.from() is insanely glitchy, but i'll try closing all background tasks and vlc player.. may also be the css float i have on the items. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions and this awareness? Fat arrow functions are not aware of this at all and will use global scope. So please me and try not using an arrow function. Then indeed I recommend using spread operator [...elem] from itterable. And if you want it on all iterate over them after selecting with querySelectorAll which will provide you each element when using I a loop like for ... in or for ... of